# Mounting a USB CD drive

Tags: usb, mount, cd-drive

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. I have a USB CD ROM drive which I want to be able to read and to eject. The drive has no physical buttons on it so I need a software eject to get my disk out. The drive does not automatically appear to automatically mount itself; I can't see it in the file browser gui. There is a CD in the drive.

The drive itself has no discernable markings on it for a brand or model or anything. `lsusb` gives

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 13fd:1140 Initio Corporation TDR-085 F810
```

I get these two lines at the end of `dmesg|tail` after inserting the drive:

```
[ 2760.282857] sr 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[ 2760.282974] sr 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 5
```

Which suggests to me that it's located at `/dev/sr1/` until I mount it. Is this correct?

I tried to mount using `sudo mount /dev/sr1 /mnt/cdrom` and I got

```
mount: /mnt/cdrom: no medium found on /dev/sr1
```

Can someone advise on how I can mount the drive? Also, how can I eject the drive? If it's possible to eject without mounting this would be useful, then I could insert a different CD and check if it's the CD that's damaged.

Comment: @user68186 yes, I edited to clarify

Comment: @user68186 it's a ps1 game. I installed jpsxdec to rip the music from it, I'll have a look if it's recognised in that program and I'll try brasero

Comment: Have you looked in /Media?

Comment: Is it possible that the CD is protected from reading and/or copying to force users to pay for each copy?

Comment: My own external USB CD/DVD seems to have behavior much like yours *when attached to an already running system*. If my drive is attached to the system before poweron and is present at boot, then it works.

Comment: @user535733 this solved my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

user535733 suggested in the comments that I boot with the drive already inserted. I tried this and it has solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-)